# Subgroup question

Tags: group-theory

From Jacobson's  Basic Algebra I , exercise 9 of section 1.2:

Let $G$ be a non-vacuous subset of a monoid M. Show that G is a subgroup if and only if every $g \in G$ is invertible in M and $g_1^{-1}g_2 \in G$ for any $g_1, g_2 \in G$.

Does Jacobson perhaps intend that every invertible element in M is also in G? This is not quite what he wrote in the exercise as I read it. Am I misreading this?

As written,
It seems $\{1,2\} \subset (N,+,0)$ is a counter example since it is not closed under the composition (+) nor contains the unit of M and is thus not a subgroup.

Comment: No, he doesn't intend that every invertible element of $M$ is in $G$. I don't understand your counterexample. What is $N$?

Comment: N is natural numbers 0,1,2,3,...

Comment: That is usually written as ${\mathbb N}$. Neither $1$ nor $2$ is invertible in ${\mathbb N}$, so the condition does not hold.

Comment: I did not know tex for that. Thanks. Ah, I am confusing identity with inverse.

Comment: Could $g_1,g_2 \in G$ allow $g_1 = g_2$ so that then unit in M must be in G

Comment: Yes that's right, and then you get $g_1^{-1}$ as $g_1^{-1}g_2$ with $g_2$ the identity.

Comment: Closure comes as well since $g_1,g_2 \in G \implies g_1^{-1},g_2 \in G \implies (g^{-1})^{-1}g_2 \in G \implies g_1g_2 \in G$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39578/discussion-between-topoquestion-and-derek-holt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Derek Holt for pointing me in the right direction. Here is an attempt at a writeup for those searching the forum:

Let $G$ be a non-vacuous subset of a monoid $M$.

Suppose every $g \in G$ is invertible in M and $g_1^{-1}g_2 \in G$ for any $g_1, g_2 \in G$.  Then $g_1,g_1 \in G \implies g_1^{-1}g_1 \in G \implies 1 \in G$ where $1$ is the unit of M.  Then $g_1 \in G \implies g_1,1 \in G \implies g_1^{-1}1 \in G \implies g_1^{-1} \in G$ Then $g_1,g_2 \in G \implies g_1^{-1},g_2 \in G \implies (g_1^{-1})^{-1}g_2 \in G \implies g_1g_2 \in G$  Thus G is a subset of M containing the unit of M, every element of G is invertible with the inverse also in G, and G is closed under the composition of M. Thus G is a subgroup.

Conversely, Suppose G is a subgroup.
By definition of subgroup, every element of G is invertible and so for any $g_1,g_2 \in G, g_1^{-1} \in G$. Then since again by definition of subgroup, G is closed under the composition so $g_1^{-1}g_2 \in G$.

Thus G is a subgroup if and only if every $g \in G$ is invertible in M and $g_1^{-1}g_2 \in G$ for any $g_1,g_2 \in G$.